# Session ID on server vs Session ID in cookies

Tags: c#, session, .net-core, cookies

I am trying to recognize users that have already visited my site (on my .NET Core server), and I've registered 
`services.AddSession()` 
in my project.

I am using attribute above my controller methods like so `[SessionRequirement]` and in the class that handles those requests, I check if session with a given ID exists and I create an entry for it in the database `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Id`.

When I test my method with Postman I receive a cookie `.AspNetCore.Session=SOME_VALUE`, but after restarting the server, when I call the method with the same cookie and check the session.Id it's different.

How can I make sure that the session will stay the same even after restarting app?

Answer (score 0):

You should store a cookie on the browser such as hasVisited=true, though if they clear their cookies this will be lost. Session IDs will not persist and are not fit for this usage

For cookies: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/